# How to make a fix header with a downloaded image in Android application

Tags: android

I'm quite new to Android. I have few activities now which have a common portion of their layouts ( which is the header indeed ) and worst thing is that header has to download clients logo over net every time activity is loaded. I wonder if I can separate screen into 2, one being a static header with logo download run only once and stays there and second one being the dynamic portion interacting with the user and changes so that application does not attempt to load header image in every other activity.

Or that does not matter much? Do android have a caching mechanism somehow to prevent such repetitive downloads for the same destination... like browsers get it from cache.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "worst thing is that header has to download clients logo over net every time activity is loaded" -- since you are downloading the logo yourself, why not cache it yourself? "Do android have a caching mechanism somehow to prevent such repetitive downloads for the same destination" -- Android doesn't, but you can do that yourself. If you provide a [mcve] showing your download code, we might be able to make specific suggestions.

Comment: Thank you. I'll work on caching it myself.